# Python3: Extracting value from XML

Tags: python, xml-parsing, extract

I would like to extract weather sun UV-index value from XML file, located here:
https://www.ilmateenistus.ee/ilma_andmed/xml/observations.php

The location of the element (uvindex) in XML is:

```
<observations timestamp="1682245130">
......
<station>
<name>Roomassaare</name>
<uvindex>4.6</uvindex>
</station>
```

In the xml file there are multiple stations with different names. I would like to get the uv index value from only one station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I'm using `beautifulsoup` to parse the XML document and store the `uvindex` into a dictionary (keys are station names):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ilmateenistus.ee/ilma_andmed/xml/observations.php'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'xml')

data = {}
for station in soup.select('station'):
    data[station.find('name').text] = station.uvindex.text

# print uvindex of station named "Tallinn-Harku":
print(data['Tallinn-Harku'])
```

Prints:

```
1.8
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working in trinket.io Python online interpreter, but in my local laptop it throws error: FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: Update: I was able to get it work using "html.parser" instead "xml" in soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'xml')

Comment: @fred You can install additional `lxml` package. `html.parser` should work too.